# Why I can not add items to the database?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

I created a database with SQLite-net and then insert an object in it in this way:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db"), true);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<Musei>();

            Musei musPref;
            musPref = new Musei
                {
                    DidascaliaLista=muss.DidascaliaLista,
                    NomeMuseo = muss.NomeMuseo,
                    Luogopreciso = muss.Luogopreciso,
                    Descrizione = muss.Descrizione,
                    NumeroTel = muss.NumeroTel,
                    IndirizzoEmail = muss.IndirizzoEmail,
                    Immagine= muss.Immagine,
                };



await conn.InsertAsync(musPref);
```

In a new page I would like to retrieve the Database show in a ListView elements within the DB

This is code c#:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db"), true);
await conn.CreateTableAsync<Musei>();
var Dbase = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db");
var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Dbase, true);

var query = await con.Table<Musei>().ToListAsync();
ListaPreferiti.Source = query;
```

This is code XAML:

```
<Page.Resource>
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="ListaPreferiti" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
</Page.Resource>
.....
<ListView x:Name="ListPreferiti" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListaPreferiti}}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListPreferiti_ItemClick" Margin="0,-1,0.667,-0.333">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Image x:Name="Cerchio" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/120.png" Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,13,0,0"/>

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding NomeMuseo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Descrizione}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/NoImage.png"/>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Luogopreciso}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid Background="Chocolate">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Beige" 
                                                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle>
                                </ListView.GroupStyle>
                            </ListView>
                        </PivotItem>
                    </Pivot>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
```

I can not understand why the ListView is empty. Just try start the application, the output of the Debug Visual Studio I see this message:

" Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found on 'App1.Musei, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='Key' DataItem='App1.Musei, App1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"

Comment: You don't have a field named Key in your table, so its telling you that it can't bind to it because it can't find a Key property. What are you attempting to do with that textblock?

Comment: I was wrong, I changed to this:  ` <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomeMuseo}" Foreground="Beige" 
                                                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/> ` Now I no longer have that mistake but I always see the empty list

Comment: Please show your observable property.